# MovieTexture error with augmented reality

Tags: unity, augmented-reality

Unity says, the following error, is this because I'm using a free Unity instead of pro ?

The type or namespace name `MovieTexture' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

tutorial what I followed:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBc3ubr18ks

Answer (score 1):

If you building your game for mobile, Unity [does not support](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html) MovieTexture for mobile platforms by default. By the way, there are [several assets](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/mobile/movie/texture) on the Store, not free though.

Comment: but the guy in the tutorial using Android with MovieTexture.

Comment: @Karoly, as [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html) says, `Movie Textures are not supported on iOS` and `Movie Textures are not supported on Android. Instead, full-screen streaming playback is provided using Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.`

Comment: ah, okay. I would like to do an augmented reality, when the user point the camera above the marker, the mp4 file starts. May I kindly ask , who would you solve it? Your help is highly appreciated .

Comment: I can't say much about mp4 playing on mobile, but [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/15215/unity-3d-and-augmented-reality.html) you can find a lot of stuff about augmented reality.